# Graph cursor dont show my data but draw it properly

Tags: mysql, timestamp, grafana

I have the next information in a mysql table:

```
+-----------------+----------+------------+----------------+---------------+
|    time_stamp   | m_value  | pt_periode | meter_id_meter | mType_id_mtype|
+-----------------+----------+------------+----------------+---------------+
|2019-03-01 00:00:00 | 1800  |    0       |      1         |      22       |
+-----------------+----------+------------+----------------+---------------+

etc
```

Well, I have three meassures (march, april and may) for the day 1 of every month at 00:00:00. When I do the next query in grafana:

```sql
SELECT
  time_stamp AS "time",
  m_value
FROM menergy
WHERE
  meter_id_meter = 1 and mtype_id_type = 22
order by
  time_stamp
```

I get the time graph that looks fine, it represent the three values at the correct time but when I put the cursor on the graph the measure value is 0 and after the correct value, the next point go to 0.

Is it a query mistake?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dcLiGdDDpxtp3Jlt5Mpqgis5d3gVZyw_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you take a screenshot of this graph ?

Comment: I'll put it in drive link because I can't insert image yet in the foro.

Comment: It was a query problem, I have more values and the difference is pt_periode, so I had to include it in the "where" part of the query....sorry I didnt explain well the situation